# Story involving a machine intelligence named Bringer, who restored humanity to Earth

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a story involving a machine intelligence named Bringer, he agreed to assist humans in a live interstellar crossing, and ended up taking them back to the earth, against other machines wishes. Humans had gone extinct on earth, partially due to some failed geo engineering by the machines, and were recreated on 'safe' planets without dangerous stars and geological activity.

I believe the story was published on the web somewhere, but I am unable to re-discover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *[The Passage Home](https://web.archive.org/web/20160207044453/http://www.localrogertoo.com/the-passage-home-part-2-of-the-mortal-passage-trilogy/)* (Part 2 of *The Mortal Passage Trilogy*) by Robert Williams

> In any rational universe I’d have long since been dismantled or
>   refactored for useful work, but the humans of Minerva would have none
>   of that. **I was the Bringer** and they wanted me preserved as a kind of
>   shrine to their origin. Having re-learned the delicate art of dealing
>   with humans I can even understand that. In the eleven thousand years
>   between the Extinction at Reykjavik and the Minervan Humanogenesis,
>   our kind had forgotten that humans can be incredibly intense,
>   perverse, contrary, violent, and nostalgic.